# Json format of data which is having HTML tags in Web API in C#

Tags: asp.net, json, rest

```
I have an object Example

Class Event
   {
       string country{get;set}
   }
   Events test = new Evnts();

test.country="<P>India<P>"
```

How i need to **Json format** for the above.

I used the method

```
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new   
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            StringContent sc = new StringContent(oSerializer.Serialize(list));
            sc.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return sc;
```

But this is giving output   result as  `"City": "\u003cp\u003eIndia\u003cp\u003e",`
Please comment on this .
Thank you

Comment: first remove html tag from script

Answer (score 0):

That's encoded <> tag representation. You shouldn't return specific html element in JSON response. Also, no need to use JavaScriptSerializer class. You can simply return your "Event" class as a result of your svc web api service.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am fetching Rich text from Sitecore Item,
I used Regex to remove the HTML tags and Replace Method to replace the "’" and Replace(" ",""). I am directly sending the List of events not using JavaScriptSerializer class.

((Regex.Replace(eve["text"].ToString(), "<[^>]*>", "").Replace("’", "'")).Replace(" ","")).Replace("\n","");

Thank you Pravin and Ivan Sivak